# Mechanism of terpene alcohol rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, rearrangements

[image]

I thought about all kinds of hydride shifts that could be possible here, but I still could not figure out how the mechanism would work.

Comment: Please edit the title to reflect more specifically what you are asking, perhaps including the type of reaction.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework and be voted down. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself. Hydride shifts are a secondary consideration when formation of a C-C bond is the primary issue. Take a look here about homework policy. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2):

Redraw the starting molecule so that the double next to the hydroxy group is pointing downwards.

Protonate the hydroxy group so that it forms water leaving a tertiary cation.

See how the double bonds are lined up to do a cascade forming the [6] ring and giving a tertiary cation at the opposite end of the newly formed-ring.

Capture that cation with water to give the product.

Comment: ...and if there is still any doubt, invert the product vertically. ;)